# Connect to different terminals via SSH

Tags: ssh, connection, ubuntu-20.04, tty, ubuntu-server

I'm using a Khadas VIM3 with Ubuntu Server 20.04 as companion computer onboard. To make it work I have to use different terminals, which I usually change with `Ctrl`+`Alt`+ `F1`to `F6`, to access the 6 different terminals (tty1 to tty6). However, now I'm interested in controlling the Khadas from another Ubuntu 20.04 computer and I already can do it through SSH, although I only managed to access the tty1.

Is it possible to use SSH to access different terminals? If so, how can it be done?

I've being looking for answers, but I couldn't find anything helpful.